# AngularJS: Removing the parent element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `li` item that repeat, according to `$scope.items` list. In each `li` I have a checkbox. What I want to do is to catch the change event of this checkbox and do my work there. Executed in `$scope.change` function.

When my work done, I want to remove the row of the checked checkbox.

My code so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
        app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
          $scope.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
          $scope.change = function() {
                // My work here.
                // ...

                // Work is done. remove the caller checkbox.
                this.parent.remove(); // <--- BOOM.
          }
        });     
  </script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="change()">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Live version is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/05IBKp6aVoj1SqFNi5JJ

My problem is in this code-line:

```
this.parent.remove(); // <--- BOOM.
```

My target is to remove the parent `li`.

### Questions:

1. How this can be done right?
2. When I using the `this` keyword (in controller.change function), is this something that I can use with JQuery syntax? Something like `$(this).parent().remove();`?

Comment: Yes, you can use it with jquery syntax.

Comment: Not working for me. See live version here: http://plnkr.co/edit/kQaSALQukbPv5Cerh8yr

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ElFt3Qvkr17M4audr3ev?p=preview check this now. Its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at this plunker, I have used ng-click to detect the change and I have passed the $event as the parameter.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
      $scope.change = function(e) {
            // My work here.
            // ...
            console.log($(this));
            console.log(e.target);
            // Work is done. remove the caller checkbox.
            $(e.target).parent().remove(); // Not working
      }
    });     
 </script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
 <div ng-controller="mainController">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-click="change($event)">
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[Remove li by passing the $event.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ElFt3Qvkr17M4audr3ev?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

You can delete the item from $scope.items and it will be automatically removed and you don't need to use jQuery.

I updated the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/3aYHQspeLAj3VryQAhBT?p=preview

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="change(item)">
</li>
```

and in JS

```
$scope.change = function(item) {
           // Work is done. remove the caller checkbox.
           var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
           $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
      }
```

Comment: just pass the index in change event. why calculate it again?

Answer (score 3):

Please do following change.

HTML:

```
<ul> <li ng-repeat="item in items"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="change($index)"> </li>
```

JS.

```
  $scope.change = function(index) { 
         $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
 }
```

Que.2

You can do this using [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) and directive.

Answer (score 3):

Changed:

html:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-click="change($event)">
   </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$scope.change = function (e) {             
    angular.element(e.target).parent().remove(); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to implement a simple checklist functionality.

You could pass the $index for onChange function and then use array.splice() method to perform the following action.

```
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
              var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
              app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$timeout) {
                $scope.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
                $scope.prevItem ={
                    value: null,
                    index: null
                }
                $scope.change = function(index) {
                 $timeout(function(){
                  // Your work here.
                  $scope.prevItem.value = $scope.items[index];
                  $scope.prevItem.index = index;
                  $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                 }, 300);
               }
               $scope.undoCheck = function(){
                $scope.items.splice($scope.prevItem.index, 0, $scope.prevItem.value);
               }
              });     
        </script>  
      </head>
      <body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-controller="mainController">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="change($index)">
              {{item}}
            </li>
          </ul>
          <button ng-click="undoCheck()">Undo Previous Check</button>
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

I have also added undo functionality to just help you get more clarity on splice function.

The timeout function is added to just show the check on the checkbox before removing it.